# Intercept managed package custom button

Tags: managed-package, custom-button

Is there a way to capture when a custom button from a managed package is clicked? What I'm trying to do is intercept when the button is clicked and then run a process to set a date. The problem with looking at the specific criteria that occurs after the button is clicked is that someone can do it manually and it needs to be captured from the button click event. Is there a way to intercept the button click? It runs a s-control, but everything is un-editable so I'm trying to come up with some creative option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to intercept the button click on a Visualforce page via Javascript, assuming that you know or can set the Id of the rendered html, or enclose the button in an html element that you can control (in which case you can attach an event handler in JS to the parent element).

From there, I don't know if you are able to run a process/flow/apex in general from Javascript (my best guess would be to look at [the @invokableMethod annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm))

The workaround that I've used for my company's usage of DocuSign is to create my own custom button to use instead of the 'send with DocuSign' button that was provided with their package.

This allowed me to redirect my users to a Visualforce page that I control, which allows me to put a controller or controller extension in the overall execution path. If you set the `action` attribute of your Visualforce page's `<apex:page>` and return a `PageReference` to the same Visualforce page that the DocuSign button would normally redirect my users to, then your users will not notice the additional visualforce page (unless you run into an exception in your controller).

Comment: That helped and pointed me in the direction I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to incercept that button in a package. However, if that button does an DML, you could intercept it with a trigger or process based on the object that is created/updated.